# Rails geocoding/geolocation options for 'find near me'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, geolocation, geocoding

I am creating an app where pet rescue centres can add pets that need homes, but I would like to add a sort option for visitors to the site that orders pets by location closest to them (either by IP geolocation or they enter a postcode or city).

- What are my options?
- Are there any cost implications I need to worry about?

Answer (score 1):

I think activerecord-postgis-adapter is what you need.Check it out https://github.com/dazuma/activerecord-postgis-adapter.